# inserting data to multiple tables from a single imported CSV in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, csv

I'm trying to import CSV file in laravel that contains data to be stored in multiple tables in mysql database. Actually I've Contacts with multiple emails, addresses, phones etc so i want them to store in their respective table along with the contactId of the contact newly created from the CSV.

For now insertion in single table is working but when i introduce columns like email, address etc that are to be inserted in other tables, it gives me column not found in Contact table as email address etc column is not there.

**Controller Method for Insertion**

```
public function processImport(Request $request){
    $data = CsvData::find($request->csv_data_file_id);
    $csv_data = json_decode($data->csv_data, true);
    foreach ($csv_data as $row) {
        $contact = new Contact();  //Insertion in Contact table
        foreach (config('app.contact_fields') as $index => $field) {
            if ($data->csv_header) {
                $contact->$field = $row[$request->fields[$field]];
            } else {
                $contact->$field = $row[$request->fields[$index]];
            }
        }
        $contact->save();   //Insertion in Contact table
        $id = $contact->id;
    }

    return 'Successfully imported!';
    }
```

Now i want to know is there any way we can separate columns to be inserted into separate tables from the single CSV imported ?
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Yes of course. Just seperate the fields a little more specifically to the table structure of the 2 tables and then put the data in the correct model

Comment: I didn't get your point please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute multiple queries inside the foreach() loop, because you have multiple tables. Without knowing the both structure of the CSV file and the tables in question it is difficult to specify any further.